# change Symbol color on click, ArcGIS runtime 100 .net

Tags: symbology, graphics, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a simple GraphicsOverlay symbol, how do I change the color of it on event triggered? 
My sample code shown below:

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        // Create new Map without basemap
        Map = new Map(SpatialReference.Create(102100));

        // Add the tile basemap only after the map has loaded so it doesn't block the map if offline
        Map.Loaded += (sender, e) => { Map.Basemap = Basemap.CreateImagery(); };

        // Setup the graphics layers
        GraphicsOverlay editGraphics = new GraphicsOverlay();
        editGraphics.Id = "MyGraphics";
        GraphicsOverlays.Add(editGraphics);

        // Add some test graphics

        SimpleMarkerSymbol pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbolStyle.Circle, SystemColor.Red, 25);
        var point = new MapPoint(0, 0);
        Graphic mapPoint = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol);
        GraphicsOverlays["MyGraphics"].Graphics.Add(mapPoint);
    }

    public ICommand ColorButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public void ColorButtonTapped()
    {
        // Handle color code goes in here
        // pointSymbol.Color = SystemColor.Gray;

    }
    public bool CanColorButtonTapped()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I thought of declaring my `SimpleMarkerSymbol pointSymbol` variable as a global variable, and simply change color like what I did in my commented out code `pointSymbol.Color = SystemColor.Gray`, But I think it is a bad approach, there should be a easy and clean way to handle it.

Comment: Do you want to change the color of all graphics in the overlay?  Or just certain ones?  If only certain ones, what are the criteria to determine which?

Comment: @zwaap It would be great if I can change the color for all of them.... I would assume something to do with "GraphicsOverlays["MyGraphics"].Graphics"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have all the graphics in an overlay use the same symbol and update them all at once, you can use a renderer.  So when you create your overlay, add the renderer like so:

```
var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(pointSymbol);
editGraphics.Renderer = renderer;
```

Then, where you want to update the color, just update the renderer's symbol, like so:

```
// Get the graphics overlay
var editGraphics = GraphicsOverlays["MyGraphics"];

// Get the symbol from the renderer and apply the color change
var renderer = editGraphics.Renderer as SimpleRenderer;
var symbol = renderer.Symbol as SimpleMarkerSymbol;
symbol.Color = newColor;
```

That will apply the change to all the graphics in the overlay.

Comment: So I guess the explicit casting is necessary in this matter then.. I did something shown below, and it works also, `var point = GraphicsOverlays["MyGraphics"].Graphics[0].symbol as SimpleMarkerSymbol  point.color = newColor` What's difference of doing it in renderer and like this..?

Comment: I was trying not to explicit cast the symbol stored in the graphics to SimpleMarkerSymbol, because I was afraid of some data loses..

Comment: @Max_Guo Casting the symbol does not in any way affect the underlying object.

As to using a renderer, that defines the symbol or set of symbols for all the graphics in an overlay.  So you can just change the renderer's symbol, and all the graphics in the overlay will update.  Additionally, if you ever add graphics to the overlay, they will inherit the symbol defined by the renderer.